# How to convert two variables (integers) to a double in R?

Tags: r, isnumeric

I have never used R before and haven't found good docs on is.numeric() or double() online.

Very simply, I am trying to take two integers and put them in a double, which I want to put in a vector, which will enter as a column. I'm trying to solve the former part.

```
endlat <- df[i, "end.station.latitude"]
endlong <- df[i, "end.station.longitude"]
end <- as.double(endlat, endlong)
```

This only stores one of the values in the variable. How does this function work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like

```
as.double(c(endlat, endlong))
```

This passes the *integer* length-2 vector containing `endlat` and `endlong` to `as.double`, which only takes one argument.

Comment: `c()` is for "creation": it creates a vector from scalars (or other vectors).